# Passagem de parametros, ele.on('click', func);

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu faço para conseguir passar parametros da seguinte forma?

```
function hello(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
$('ele').on('click', hello);
```

Como consigo passar a `msg` para a a função `hello();`

A alternativa com javascript nativo também é bem vinda.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar o parâmetro na sequencia, e ele será adicionado no data dentro do parâmetro do evento:

```
function hello(event) {
    alert(event.data.msg);
}

$('#ele').on('click', {msg: 'Teste'}, hello);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkaLnyvs/)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui da seguinte maneira, não sei se é o mais correto mas:

```
function hello(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
$('ele').on('click', function() { hello('hello') });
```

```js
function hello(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
$('button').on('click', function() { hello('hello') });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hello</button>
```